# TextView, won't set text

Tags: java, android

I have a hashmap full of values which will populate the listview. the image sets fine but the text does not. The hashmap is not null, just some odd reason why it would not display. Any help would be appreciated

```java
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
    }
    TextView description = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.description); 
    TextView username = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.usernamae); 
    TextView likes = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.likes); 
    ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image); // thumb image
    HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();        
    song = data.get(position);
    description.setText(song.get(MenuActivity.KEY_description));
    username.setText(song.get(MenuActivity.KEY_username));
    likes.setText(song.get(MenuActivity.KEY_likes));
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(song.get(MenuActivity.KEY_THUMB_URL), thumb_image);
    return vi;
}
```

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip" >

   <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image_bg"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/list_image"
            android:layout_width="50dip"
            android:layout_height="50dip"
           />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/description"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail" />

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/likes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/username"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>


     <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try to print the text you want to set in log cat .. may be the key is not present .. check for the key if its present or not before setting the text

Comment: try to run in debug mode and set a breakpoint at song = and analyse wether this var is empty

Comment: Checked all of that. Everything is there. debugged everything, still lost as to why this is happening.

Comment: post your complete code of getView() method

Comment: @TooTiredToDrink Try like this     `description.setText(""+song.get(MenuActivity.KEY_description));`

Comment: can you print anything with likes.getText() after you set it ? This will tell you if the View contains the text. IF so, the issue might be with the layout, you might want to post that here, too.

Comment: This happens if the **"KEY"** for the **"VALUE"** does not exist. Please check your variables `KEY_discription` , `KEY_usename` etc.

Comment: @ToodeeJa-Py so `getText()` showed me that it did set. now really confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to show text using the layout you provided above, but only for "description" and "username", "likes" is hidden behind the last ImageView, try using `android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/id_of_image"`for likes. I only did a quick test with square images, depending on your actual images, you might have more hidden views, but this confirms the issue lies with the xml. Try rearranging your xml so your views don't overlap each other. 
Happy coding !

Answer (score 2):

Try use `description.setText(String.valueOf(song.get(MenuActivity.KEY_description)));`

Also try rebuild your project.

EDIT:

I watch your xml, you also add extra ", look:

```
android:id="@+id/"description"
```

need write like this:

```
 android:id="@+id/description"
```

Comment: Thank you, on the XML! Wouldn't of noticed!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried if text shows in the TextViews, if you hard-code a string in the layout XML for the TextViews? Maybe the views are just not visible, try re-arranging your layout in that case.

Answer (score 0):

```
     description.setText(song.get(MenuActivity.KEY_description).toString());
     username.setText(song.get(MenuActivity.KEY_username).toString());
     likes.setText(song.get(MenuActivity.KEY_likes).toString());
```